# data-toggle breaks after form submit

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an form in my web app that is displayed via data-toggle. I'm altering the behavior of the submit event because I want to submit data without reloading the page. I can submit the form successfully and the toggle folds as expected, but afterwards, I can no longer collapse the form to use it again. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I control the submit event

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
  //event.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit ' + $("input[name=personName]").val());
  //console.log('submit ' + $('#personName').val());
  //socket.emit('add', $('#personName').val());
  socket.emit('add', $("input[name=personName]").val());
  //$('#personName').val('');
  $("input[name=personName]").val('');
  //$("#add-person-panel").toggle();
  $("div[id=add-person-panel]").toggle();
  $("div[id=add-person-panel]").addBack('aria-expanded','false');
  //$("input[name=personName]").toggle();
  //$('#add-person-panel').attr('aria-expanded','');
  //socket.emit('add', $('input[name=personName]'));

  //$('input[name=personName]').val("");

  return false; //do not let the page refresh on submit

});
```

form

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <%
         if (hasKioskPermissions === true || hasDigmaKioskPermissions === true){ %>
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#add-person-panel" class="collapsed">
            "Add Person To Local Queue"
            ::after
          </a>
         <% } else { %>
          <a data-toggle="collapse disabled" href="#add-person-panel" class="collapsed">
            "Add Person To Local Queue"
            ::after
          </a>
         <%}%>
      </div>
      <div id="add-person-panel" class="panel-body collapse">
        <form data-parsley-validate="" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-8">
                <input name="personName" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter name" required class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Adding..." class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `$('div#add-person-panel')` instead of `$("div[id=add-person-panel]")`.
2. What is the template type? It's not plain html. There are `<%  %>` in the code.
3. Are you trying to use server-side sockets in browser (`socket.emit(...)`)?

**UPD**

Did you initialize your socket before using?

There is an example from [docs](http://socket.io/docs/):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });   });
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Thanks I'll try it.  
2. I'm using ejs.
3. I'm using socket.io to send data between client and server.  I have a bigger reason for using it than just the form.

Comment: Are you sure that your socket.io library loaded properly?

Comment: @user3389171 Is socket.io a server-side library?
Do you run script you provided on a user side in a browser?

Comment: Yes.  I'm logging the connection and the results when they are sent. Unfortunatlely, $('div#add-person-panel') did not work.

Comment: Please make it clear – where that JS code runs: server-side or client-side?

Comment: Please explain.  The issue I'm having is getting the toggle to work after I submit the first time.  How does this help?

Comment: You did not provide the whole code, so I'm not sure that you code is good or not. I could not guess did you link your socket library or not, did you initialized socket or not. If you didn't, you should get an error in line you trying to call `socket.emit()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not using the same plugin (from bootstrap) to close as I did with open. This is necessary since the plugin tracks it's own state.

before:

$('div#add-person-panel').toggle();

after:

$('div#add-person-panel').collapse('hide');

minimal solution below:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit ' + $("input[name=personName]").val());




  $("input[name=personName]").val('');

  $('div#add-person-panel').collapse('hide');
  $('div#add-person-panel').addBack('aria-expanded','false');

  return false; //do not let the page refresh on submit

});
```